# Force SVNKit library to use the public key of currently logged in user?

Tags: java, bash, svn

On bash I can just run `svn add myfile` or `svn commit myfile` because the public key of my user is inside the `authorized_keys` file of the SVN user (in `svn+ssh://svn-user@svn-server.ch/app/svn/repo/test/jars/apps` `svn-user` would be the user) on the SVN server.

Is it possible to tell SVNKit somehow to do the authentication over above configuration? Because no matter what I try, it just fails.

The following was my last try.

```
SVNSSHAuthentication auth = new SVNSSHAuthentication("myuser", 
new File("/opt/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa"), null, 22, true, null, false);

log.debug("private key -> " + auth.getPrivateKeyFile().getAbsolutePath());

BasicAuthenticationManager authMgr = new BasicAuthenticationManager(
new SVNAuthentication[] { auth });

clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
clientManager.setAuthenticationManager(authMgr);

clientManager.getCommitClient()
.doCommit(new File[] { file }, false, message, null, null,
false, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
```

I am getting the following exception.

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: 
Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'svn-user@svn+ssh://svn-server.ch'
```

How do I do it properly? I have no passphrase and use my public key on Linux command line and want to use same way inside java. I would also like to avoid providing the SVNUrl if that's somehow possible.

Comment: Down voter do you mind commenting the down vote?

Comment: You need to pass the private key.